# Ajax Post PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending some data using AJAX, I can get most of it working apart from the final data value.

I would like to declare a PHP variable at the beginning of my HTML file, then reference this in the AJAX post - is this possible?

MY code is;

```
<?php 
$location = 'My Office';
?>

$.ajax({
    url: "my url",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        Feedback: feedbackVal,
        Date: date,
        Time: time,
        Location: <?php echo $location; ?>
    }
});
```

The error I receive in the console is;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Screenshot of console;

[image]

When I remove `Location` from the AJAX post the remaining data sends successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stringify it like `Location: "<?php echo $location; ?>"`.

Comment: your json syntax has to be correct ! You are missing quotes around the value for `location`..., as the console screenshots points out !

Comment: In your code, the value of `url` is a string. Why do you expect the value of `Location` to be something else?

Comment: can't u just make:  `Location: $location`

Comment: maybe `Location: "<?php echo $location; ?>"` , but i don't recommend using php in js ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this;

```
  Location: "<?php echo $location; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string value on Location

```
$.ajax({
   url: "my url",
   type: "post",
   data: {
      Feedback: "feedbackVal",
      Date: "date",
      Time: "time",
      Location: "<?php echo $location; ?>"
   }
});
```

Otherwise it will consider as a variable name.